# VALORES NULOS AL UNIR CONSULTAS CON JOIN

Tags: mysql

me solicitan hacer una consulta con el total de las ventas por fechas, y posteriormente hacer por separado consultas con el total de las ventas por región. Al realizarlas por separado, arroja cada una los valores de manera correcta. sin embargo al unirlas con el método `join`, los valores de las columnas de la venta de la región arroja `null`.

```
SELECT 
CAST(HEADER.OrderDate AS DATE) AS OrderDate,
SUM(HEADER.SubTotal) AS ventas,
ventasUSA.ventasUSA AS ventasUSA,
ventasEUROPA.ventasEUROPA,
ventasPACIFICO.ventasPACIFICO
FROM avetureworks.salesOrderHeader AS HEADER
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesTerritory AS Territorio
ON HEADER.TerritoryID = Territorio.TerritoryID

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT 
CAST(HEADER.orderDate AS DATE) AS orderDate,
SUM(HEADER.subTotal) as ventasUSA
FROM avetureworks.salesOrderHeader AS HEADER
INNER JOIN avetureworks.salesterritory AS Territorio
ON HEADER.TerritoryID = Territorio.TerritoryID
WHERE Territorio.Group="North America"
GROUP BY HEADER.orderDate) AS ventasUSA
ON ventasUSA.OrderDate=HEADER.OrderDate
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT 
CAST(HEADER.orderDate AS DATE) AS orderDate,
SUM(HEADER.subTotal) as ventasEUROPA
FROM avetureworks.salesOrderHeader AS HEADER
INNER JOIN avetureworks.salesterritory AS Territorio
ON HEADER.TerritoryID = Territorio.TerritoryID
WHERE Territorio.Group="Europe"
GROUP BY HEADER.orderDate) AS ventasEUROPA
ON HEADER.OrderDate=ventasEUROPA.OrderDate
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT 
CAST(HEADER.orderDate AS DATE) AS orderDate,
SUM(HEADER.subTotal) as ventasPACIFICO
FROM avetureworks.salesOrderHeader AS HEADER
INNER JOIN avetureworks.salesterritory AS Territorio
ON HEADER.TerritoryID = Territorio.TerritoryID
WHERE Territorio.Group="Pacific"
GROUP BY HEADER.orderDate)  ventasPACIFICO
ON HEADER.OrderDate=ventasPACIFICO.OrderDate
GROUP BY 
HEADER.OrderDate,
ventasUsa.ventasUSA,
ventasEUROPA.VentasEUROPA,
ventasPACIFICO.ventasPACIFICO
ORDER BY orderDate
```